# Some properties in differential geometry of curves and surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-verification

Let $\beta, \alpha$ be curves in $\mathbb{R}^3$ parametrized by arc length. Suppose $\beta$ is obtained by rotating $\alpha.$ Let $t_{\alpha}, n_{\alpha}, b_{\alpha}$ (resp. $t_{\beta}, n_{\beta}, b_{\beta}$ ) denote Frenet trihedron of $\alpha$ (resp. $\beta$).

Then, $\beta(s)=A\alpha(s),$ for some orthogonal matrix $A$ with determinant $1.$

Show that $t_{\beta}=At_{\alpha}, \ n_{\beta}=An_{\alpha},\  b_{\beta}=Ab_{\alpha},  \ \kappa_{\alpha}=\kappa_{\beta}, \ \tau_{\alpha}=\tau_{\beta}. $

May I know if my proof is correct? Thank you.

Lemma(1): $u\in \mathbb{R}^3 \mapsto Au \in \mathbb{R^3}$ is onto.

Lemma(2): Given $u \in \mathbb{R^3},\|Au\|^2=(Au)^TAu=u^Tu=\|u\|^2, $ i.e. $\|Au\|=\|u\|$

Lemma(3):Given $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^3,\left \langle {Au,Av}\right \rangle=\left \langle {u,v}\right \rangle$

Lemma(4): Given $u,v,w \in \mathbb{R}^3, \left \langle {u \times v, w}\right \rangle = [u,v,w],$ where $[u,v,w]=$ determinant of matrix with $u,v,w$(taken in order) as columns  (just expand out)

Lemma(5): $\left \langle {u,v}\right \rangle=\left \langle {u,w}\right \rangle \Rightarrow v=w$

Inductively, we can show $\beta ^{(n)} = A\alpha^{(n)}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.$

Then, clearly, $\beta^{\prime}=t_{\beta}=At_{\alpha}=A\alpha^{\prime}$

By Lemma(2), $\kappa_{\beta}=\|\beta^{\prime\prime}\|=\|A\alpha^{\prime\prime}\| = \|\alpha^{\prime\prime}\| = \kappa_{\alpha}$

Since $n_{\beta}=\dfrac{\kappa_{\alpha}}{\kappa_{\beta}}An_{\alpha},$ we have $n_{\beta}= An_{\alpha}.$

By Lemma(1), given $z \in \mathbb{R}^3, \exists z^{\prime} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $z=Az^{\prime}$

$ \left \langle {b_{\beta}, z}\right \rangle $

$=  \left \langle {At_{\alpha} \times An_{\alpha}, z}\right \rangle$

$=[At_{\alpha}, An_{\alpha}, Az'],$ by Lemma(4)

$=det(A)[t_{\alpha},n_{\alpha},z']$

$= \left \langle {t_{\alpha} \times n_{\alpha}, z'}\right \rangle,$ since $det(A)=1$ and by Lemma(4).

$=\left \langle {A(t_{\alpha} \times n_{\alpha}), Az'}\right \rangle,$ by Lemma (3)

$=\left \langle {A(b_{\alpha}), z}\right \rangle$

By Lemma(5), $b_{\beta}=Ab_{\alpha}.$

By Lemma(4), $\tau_{\beta}=\left \langle {n_{\beta},b'_{\beta}}\right \rangle=\left \langle {An_{\alpha},Ab'_{\alpha}}\right \rangle = \left \langle {n_{\alpha},b'_{\alpha}}\right \rangle = \tau_{\alpha}.$